# Is there a phrase or word to describe an algorithim or program is complete in that given any value for its arguments there is a defined outcome?

Tags: algorithms, terminology

Is there a phrase or word to describe an algorithm or program is complete in that given any value for its arguments there is a defined outcome? i.e. all the ramifications have been considered whatever the context?

A simple example would be the below function:

```
function returns string get_item_type(int type_no)
{
  if(type_no < 10)
    return "hockey stick"
  else if (type_no < 20)
    return "bulldozer"
  else
    return "unknown"
}
```

(excuse the dismal pseudo code)

No matter what number is supplied all possibilities are catered for. My question is: is there a word to fill the blank here:

```
"get_item_type() is ______ complete"
```

?

(The answer is  not Turing Complete - that is something quite different - but I annoyingly always think of something as "Turing Complete" when I am thinking of the above).

Comment: "It's working"?

Comment: If I remember my CS correctly that's actually a *requirement* for anything to be called an "algorithm" in the strict sense: it must finish in finite time with a defined result on every possible input.

Comment: how about "functional complete"?

Comment: I am actually struggling to find out what would be an algorithm where it is false that "given any possible value for its arguments there is a predicatable outcome". Ok, the C specification sometimes uses `undefined behaviour`, but even in this case implementations actually define one. Even random number generators can only be pseudo random, and look random because we do not consider in the input state such as the computer clock.

Comment: To be more precise, even if your example lacked the else clause, you still would have a pretty well-defined behaviour: either a compilation error, which means that you failed to specify correctly your algorithm after all, or some default return value, such as `nil`, depending on the language

Comment: In the abstract sense (without an underlying language) if you missed the else clause you would not have an actual algorithm, only part of it

Comment: @Andrea: an example would be an "algorithm" that doesn't terminate at all on some inputs (for example it has an infinite loop). Other examples are ill-defined algorithm, such as an algorithm over N that says "if input = 1 return true, if input = 2 return false" is not defined for input = 3. That the *implementation* actually does something when input = 3 does not mean that the algorithm is "well-defined".

Comment: That seems to me predictable and deterministic. It just does not spit out a result, and this is what you expect.

Comment: @Andrea: that's all good and well, but from what I learned it's not an algorithm until it ends in finite time for all inputs. Yes, it *can* be predictable and deterministic and still loop forever, but it's not an algorithm in that case.

Comment: I think we agree. But I still do not understand the question :-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I do not agree with your restriction that an algorithm has to terminate for all input values. Consider the following pseudo code with n as input: while (n != 1) { if n is odd then n := 3*n+1 else n:=n/2} I'd consider this an algorithm. But it is an open problem if this will terminate for all integers n (mathematical not Java). It is known as Collatz conjecture. So following your definition, nobody knows if it is an algorithm. That's why I think your requirement is to restrictive.

Comment: It is a pure function; it also describes a stateless / memory-less http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system

Comment: @Andrea instead of "there is a predictable outcome" I could have said "there is a user defined outcome", of course in any actual implementation there is a predictable outcome but im talking the logical sense. (An implementation has a predictable outcome in a particular programming language and environment but that is an  implementation detail - my above function taken as pseudo code will have the same outcome regardless of implementation therefore it is deterministic. Whereas if I did not have the else condition it would depend on the impelmentation what the outcome is going to be).

Comment: or even better "there is a defined outcome" - I shall change the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could say it is a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

or if there is state to be considered besides the arguments you could say it is [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm)

Comment: I'd go with deterministic.

Comment: For me pure function means that it does not have any other side-effects apart from the return value. I don't think that's required for the word the OP looks for. "deterministic" sounds more like it.

Comment: I thought about "deterministic" too, but IMO deterministic means more: a deterministic function's result only depends on the arguments, not on state.

Comment: having read up on deterministic - is does depend on the arguments - but also each state thereon is pre-determined: i.e. deterministic!

Comment: Neither of these cover the meaning of being well-defined for all possible inputs. "Pure" means the function does not have any side effects, so that the same set of input invariably produces the same output; "deterministic" means that the function always has the same effect, given identical program state and inputs.

Comment: @tdammers is right, the answer suggests phrases which have different meanings, thus -1.

Answer (score 13):

Mathematically speaking, the term you are looking for is "[Total Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_function)" (a function that is defined for every possible value in some domain), as opposed to a "partial function", which is only defined for a subset of the possible input values.

Note that, strictly speaking, mathematical functions are always total on their own domain; calling a function "partial" only makes sense if you offset it against another domain, such as the function `f(x) = 1/x`: the domain of this function is the domain of all real numbers except zero, but against the domain of all real numbers (including zero), it is partial.

In programming, the types of a function's inputs state a domain already, and by not defining the function for all of them, you could say that the function is partial. However, many programming languages fall back to a default behavior when you don't explicitly return anything - they may return 0, `null`, `undefined`, etc. Technically speaking, such functions are still total - they return a value for all possible inputs -, but conceptually, there are gaps in the definition. And not all programming languages feature such fallbacks; the alternatives are refusing to compile, responding with "undefined behavior", raising an exception, etc.

BTW, note that neither determinism nor purity have anything to do with this. A deterministic function is one that always has the same effect given the same context (relevant system state and inputs); a pure function is a function that does not have any side effects (so that it always returns the same value given the same inputs, regardless of any outside state, and without influencing outside state in any way). You can easily come up with a function that is partial, yet fully deterministic (provided that partial functions are legal in your programming language, and definition gaps are handled in a predicatable way); and conversely, if you manage to write a non-deterministic function, e.g. by reading from a hardware entropy source, there is no reason why it would have to be total (nor partial). The same goes for purity, unless a definition gap automatically introduces side effects (then all pure functions must also be total).

Comment: +1. BTW any Turing complete language allows you to write a partial function by implementing an algorithm that will not terminate for at least some of the possible input values. (Still they are completely deterministic.)

Answer (score 4):

## In Your Case...

In your particular example, what we have is a [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) [(partial) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

*<sub>(Don't be mislead by the "partial". See below.)</sub>*

---

To answer your question, we need to consider these:

## Algorithms and Functions

Algorithms are implemented using either:

- a [pure fuction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (side-effects free), resulting in a [deterministic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) (results are predictable and transposed to a [mathematical function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)),
- or an impure function, resulting in a [non-deterministic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).

## Functions

Functions can also considered as being either:

- a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) (there's an output for all possible input),
- a [total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_function) (perfect input-output pairing).

## Function Types

Furthermore, consider the following types of functions from a mathematical perspective:

#### [An Injective Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)

*A partial function where results are unique.*

[image: An Injective Function's Domain Correspondance]

#### [A Surjective Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)

*A partial function where results can overlap.*

[image: A Surjective Function's Domain Correspondance]

#### [A Bijective Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)

*A Total Function, both [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function), where there's an output for all possible inputs, and where all possible outputs are distinct and obtained by a unique input, thus being perfectly paired.*

[image: A Bijective Function's Domain Correspondance]